# Printing the elements of an array passed to a function?

Tags: arrays, c, function

Sorry if I'm asking a question that's already answered somewhere, but I am trying to work out how to write a function that firstly gets passed an array, then prints the elements of the array just passed to it.

```
void print_array(float stdarray[], int array_size)
{
    int i ;

    for (i = 0 ; i < array_size ; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", stdarray[i]) ;
    }
}
```

This was the chunk given to us, and this was the little exercise:

Modify the previous program to use the print_array function above for printing the
elements of the array passed to it (Tip: To pass an array as input in a function call, just
specify the array name without the square brackets [ ] ). That is, replace the purple
section of code with a call to the print_array function.

This isn't a graded question or marked, it's just an extra brain teaser my university is getting me to do, so I assure you I'm not cheating! I'm a little bit out of practice since I was on holidays, so if anyone could help that'd be great!

Edit: Apologies for the purple section, but I am not sure what they mean either, as it's in a black and white textbook section :). I appreciate the help.

There is another text of code above this that prints out an array's element, but if that isn't the main text then I'm not sure what is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

int main(void) 
{
    float numbers[N] ;
    int i ;

    for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
        printf("Enter number: ") ;
        scanf("%f", &numbers[i]) ;
    }
    for (i = (N - 1) ; i >= 0 ; i--){
        printf("%f\n", numbers[i]) ;
    }

    return(0) ;
}
```

Comment: We don't know what the "purple section" is. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I am trying to work out how to write a function that firstly gets passed an array, then prints the elements of the array just passed to it." They already wrote this function for you. The assignment is **not about** writing that function. The assignment is about **calling** that function. (Just to make sure, do you understand what it means to call a function?) "That is, replace the purple section of code with a call to the print_array function." We can't possibly tell you how to replace that part of the code, unless we see it.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't giving us all the code, this is JUST the function. They are now asking you to call it. We don't know how to do that, but generally it will be something along the lines of

```
print_array(arrayName, sizeof(arrayName))
```

sizeof should be a built in function, but basically you need to also pass in the size of the array that was created.

There could be other things needed, like the name of the class before the call.

Comment: Given the lack of clarity in the question, something like this is better suited to a comment. Good news: you should gain that privilege quite soon!

Comment: Sidenote: `sizeof(arrayName)`  will here _not_ give the result OP needs.